# How can I use /execute to run a command on a named item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to do `/execute @e[type=Item,name=Test] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone`

Why does this not work? and what command should i be doing?

Comment: I think you had to include quotes around the names.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do with this command and what you want to fill in the name variable?

Comment: That command does work if the item **entity** is called Test. I assume what you want is to select an item entity containing an item that has been renamed in an anvil?

Comment: @colorfusion yea, I want to use the item thats named with an anvil, I could just summon an item with a custom name but that would be temporary, and as soon as I pick it up it would be worthless

Comment: @Enderploop I'm pretty sure the `name` selector doesn't work on the Item entity. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Judge2020 ok, how would I make it to a certain item like a redstone torch?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this would be to use the Tag feature added in the 1.9 snapshots.
`/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add (tagname) {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:customname}}}}`
This item is now marked with you tagname and you can use
`/execute @e[type=Item,tag=tagname] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone`

If you cannot use the 1.9 snapshots, you can do the same thing by using a scoreboard objective instead of a tag, and setting the item's score to 1, then testing for that score.